# Squid proxy connectivity from kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, squid, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I was able to successfully setup the proxy server in Azure and using it on my browser to verify. I have an application running on a Kubernetes pod to which I have passed the proxy url as environment variable. The pod is configured as a daemonSet. As soon as I put in the proxy url - below is the error I get:

```
`/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:120:in `error!': 503 "Service Unavailable" (Net::HTTPFatalError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:129:in `value'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:715:in `transmit'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/resource.rb:51:in `get'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/kubeclient-1.1.4/lib/kubeclient/common.rb:328:in `block in api'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/kubeclient-1.1.4/lib/kubeclient/common.rb:58:in `handle_exception'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/kubeclient-1.1.4/lib/kubeclient/common.rb:327:in `api'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/kubeclient-1.1.4/lib/kubeclient/common.rb:322:in `api_valid?'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter-2.1.2/lib/fluent/plugin/filter_kubernetes_metadata.rb:234:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:164:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/agent.rb:152:in `add_filter'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/agent.rb:70:in `block in configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/agent.rb:64:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/root_agent.rb:112:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/engine.rb:131:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/engine.rb:96:in `run_configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:795:in `run_configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:579:in `dry_run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:597:in `supervise'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:502:in `run_supervisor'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:310:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/fluentd-1.2.0/bin/fluentd:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/fluentd:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/fluentd:22:in `<main>'
```

The pod at this juncture does not start with the error of `CrashLoopBackOff`.

Any help would be great. Also, if any other information required - I'll add on. Mention it please.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in the image.

Comment: In that case, curl also shouldn't have worked on the proxy in the pod. But it works

Comment: Can you test the image locally and if it works well with the proxy you set in Azure?